# Is there a bot that gives a specific role to a user when a command is typed?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to make a quiz. If a person types a command like !answer , the bot gives a role, say level 2. The next time the person answers correctly, they get the next role, like level 3.

Comment: There can be everything if someone makes it. Do you need a tutorial on how to make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`discord.Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles). So an add role code could be something along the lines of this:

```py
@client.command(name='give_me_role')
async def give_me_role(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Level 2')
    try:
        await ctx.message.author.add_roles(role)
    except discord.errors.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send('I do not have the permissions, please try again')
    except AttributeError: # ctx.message.author is a `discord.User` object, they are not in the guild
        pass
```